# Why do Tracker.exe response file errors still occur when TrackFileAccess is turned off?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2010 and trying to build a .NET 2.0 project on either of two Windows Server 2008 (x86) build machines. The build machines have .NET versions 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, and Windows SDK 7.0A installed (along with TFS 2010 and Visual Studio 2010).

Since some seemingly minor refactoring changes this week, the project builds are now always marked as partially succeeded: although the compilation finishes with no errors, TFS encounters seven Tracker.exe errors. For example, in the build summary, the following report is shown:

```
Other Errors and Warnings
7 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Tracker.exe: Response file C:\Users\Builder\AppData\Local\Temp\5647f0a8ac7a4d53b87a8c2ebca3c4f5.rsp not found.
Tracker.exe: Response file C:\Users\Builder\AppData\Local\Temp\5647f0a8ac7a4d53b87a8c2ebca3c4f5.rsp not found.
Tracker.exe: Response file C:\Users\Builder\AppData\Local\Temp\5647f0a8ac7a4d53b87a8c2ebca3c4f5.rsp not found.
Tracker.exe: Response file C:\Users\Builder\AppData\Local\Temp\5647f0a8ac7a4d53b87a8c2ebca3c4f5.rsp not found.
Tracker.exe: Response file C:\Users\Builder\AppData\Local\Temp\5647f0a8ac7a4d53b87a8c2ebca3c4f5.rsp not found.
Tracker.exe: Response file C:\Users\Builder\AppData\Local\Temp\5647f0a8ac7a4d53b87a8c2ebca3c4f5.rsp not found.
Tracker.exe: Response file C:\Users\Builder\AppData\Local\Temp\5647f0a8ac7a4d53b87a8c2ebca3c4f5.rsp not found.
```

The conventional fix for Tracker.exe errors is to disable incremental builds by passing `/p:TrackFileAccess=false` to MSBuild or by adding `TrackFileAccess=false` to the configuration settings in the MSBuild project. In the past, this has always fixed Tracker.exe issues.

However, this time the Tracker.exe errors still occur, even though there is no longer a need to track changes after turning `TrackFileAccess` off. I even went as far as to rename `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Tracker.exe` on the build machine -- and the error still occurred (I was expecting an error to say that Tracker.exe could not be found).

What could be going on here? I've searched the build machine's file system for other copies of Tracker.exe. Could it be that a build definition or MSBuild project settings are getting overridden? Thanks!

Comment: Information from further research: we branched the code and upgraded the solution from .NET 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005 to .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010. The Tracker.exe errors no longer occur on the .NET 4.0 and VS2010 branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this related to WiX in some way? I only get these in my release build. [this is your msdn link?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/5d2ec0d5-82d2-4b8a-b520-416e32f7d88c)

Comment: Yes, that is the MSDN post for the issue. Hey, it could have been due to Wix, yes. Good suggestion: we always seemed to be some problem or other caused by using Wix. Unfortunately, I can't check because I now work for a different company, which doesn't do Windows development. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You state that you have renamed the only instance of 'Tracker.exe' of you build server, yet the build wasn't affected at all.
Can it be that the actual build happens on a different Computer (build agent), this is quite possible with the TFS 2010 build topology:
[image]
An easy way to determine the server where your actual build took place is to check your build log, hopefully one with verbosity=diagnostic. Open 'View Log' and search for "Run on Agent". You should get something like
 `Run On Agent (reserved build agent <agentName> - <serverName>)`
 obviously `<serverName>` is where it all happened.
Regarding your concern *Could it be that a build definition or MSBuild project settings are getting overridden?* : again, your best bet it to check the build log. Search for `MSBuild Log File`, this should send you to a region where the actual MSBuild callup is traced.

Comment: Thanks Pantelif. I had renamed Tracker.exe on a build machine, not the server, and forced the build to be run on that build machine. As error still occurred, Tracker.exe must be running on the server, rather than the build agent.  I don't want to change Tracker.exe on the server because that will affect other projects, so I'm currently digging through thirty thousand lines of diagnostic build log output.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by adding a database project (project GUID `{00D1A9C2-B5F0-4AF3-8072-F6C62B433612}`) dll reference to an existing assembly. Removing this reference (I was only using it to force a db script rebuild on test) solved the problem.